# OleDBException was unhandled vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Not too sure what this error really means?

[image: Exception detailed]

Comment: Please put the image in your post.  Don't link to the image elsewhere.

Comment: Im not allowed to embed pictures yet

Comment: There is primary key-Foreign key relation between two tables. Try inserting record first in `tblBookType`.

Answer (score 1):

Without more information about your database schema, the error most likely means there is a foreign key relationship between the table you're trying to insert a record into -- i.e. the "foreign key" table -- and another table -- i.e. the "primary key" table.  You cannot insert a record into your target table without first having an existing record in the primary key table whose primary key value is what you're trying to insert into the foreign key column in your target table.